# Function that finds average length of sentence using arrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an assignment that requires the building of a function that goes through an ArrayList of words and finds the average length of the sentence.
My function passes 2 of the 3 tests, the last one does not pass because the punctuation that I am searching for is removed, because it stands by itself in an ArrayList slot, and is removed when using a punctuation-removing function called cleanUp. It is a little difficult to explain, so I will show all relevant parts of the code.

```
static String cleanUp(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\W*)(.*?)(\\W*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    m.matches();
    return str.substring(m.end(1), m.end(2)).toLowerCase();    
}

static double averageSentenceLength(ArrayList<String> text) {
    double sentences = 0;
    double realLength = 0;
    boolean doublePunctuation = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++){
      if(cleanUp(text.get(i)).length() != 0) {
        realLength++;
        if(text.get(i).substring(text.get(i).length()-1).equals( "." ) || 
           text.get(i).substring(text.get(i).length()-1).equals( "!" ) || 
           text.get(i).substring(text.get(i).length()-1).equals( "?" ))
          sentences++;
      } 
    }
    return realLength / sentences;
}
```

The test that it not passing:

```
public void testaverageSentenceLength2() {
    String[] textArray = {"The", "time", "has", "**********************","come,", "the", "Walrus", "said",
      "To", "talk", "of", "many", "thi-ngs:", "of", "shoes", "-", "and", "ships", "-", "and", "sealing", "wax", ",",
      "Of", "cabbages;", "and","!#$@", "kings","?",
      "And", "why", "the", "sea", "is", "boi.ling", "hot;",
      "and", "whe;ther", "pigs", "have", "win.gs!"};
    ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String str : textArray) {
      text.add(str);
    }    
    double avg = FindAuthor.averageSentenceLength(text);
    assertTrue("Average sentence length of the sample should be 17.5 but was "+avg,approx(avg,17.5));   
}
```

The Problem occurs because of the question mark after "king" that is not being counted, and therefore the average sentence length is double what it should be.

Comment: Average length of sentences or words?

Comment: What is the meaning of your title?

Comment: @cricket_007  Average amount of words per sentence

Answer (score 0):

In your `cleanup()` method, `str.substring(m.end(1), m.end(2)).toLowerCase()` is returning an empty string when the `?` string is processed, so the body of your `if` is never executed:

```
if(cleanUp(text.get(i)).length() != 0) {
    realLength++;
    if(text.get(i).substring(text.get(i).length()-1).equals( "." ) || 
        text.get(i).substring(text.get(i).length()-1).equals( "!" ) || 
        text.get(i).substring(text.get(i).length()-1).equals( "?" ))
        sentences++;
}
```